# jQuery Ajax method data parameter send a Number

Tags: ajax, jquery

excuse my bad english first,

im using ajax call and the code goes like this :

```
$.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php',
            type: 'GET',
            **data: { temp : 'counter' },**
            success: function(data){
                $('#rules2').append(data);  
        }
```

The problem is that i want the counter to be a number...i gave already set it as 
var counter = 1;
but what it does is to just send the string "counter".

Any help for this?

What i want to do is to get some data from the db with the fetch.php file and get that data by the id ...so id is a number and i need to send a number with ajax method.

Thx

Comment: it's sending a string because your creating a string. should be pointing to the variable. `data: { temp : counter },` (no single quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'fetch.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { temp : counter }, // Note the missing quotation marks
    success: function(data) {
        $('#rules2').append(data);  
}
```